# Showing $ x^{100} = O(e^{x^{1/2}}) $

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show that $ x^{100} = O(e^{x^{1/2}}), x > 1 $
Since both functions are positive, I have to show that

$ x^{100} \le ce^{x^{1/2}} $ so 
$$ 100 ln(x) \le ln(c) + \sqrt{x} $$
$$ 100 ln(x) - \sqrt{x} \le k $$ for every x > 1.

First, is this correct?
Second, if it is correct, I don't know how to prove it.  Any help would be appreciated. Actually, I could do it with optimisation, but I'd like a more formal way to prove it. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: try dividing the exponential by x^100and showing that it goes to infinity as x goes to infinity. You can use the taylor series to simplify things.

Comment: Have you at least tried graphing $100\ln x - \sqrt x$ to see if it looks like it is below some constant? https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+100+ln%28x%29-sqrt%28x%29

Comment: I used optimization to conclude that the function reaches a maximum when x = 200^2.  (the derivative is positive until that point, then negative for any x over this).  But I want to find a formal proof that this function has a superior bound.  Something that doesn't involve calculus.

Comment: Tag the question with [Asymptotics] so that more viewers can see the question on the right tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is right but not straightforward.Just take the L.H.S. & prove it equal to O(R.H.S.)$$L.H.S.=x^{100}$$taking log 
$$\log (L.H.S.)=100\log x $$taking log again
$$\log\log(L.H.S.)=\log 100+\log{\log x}\tag{1.}$$
& 
$$\log(R.H.S.)=\sqrt{x}$$log again:-
$$\log\log(R.H.S.)=\frac{1}{2}\log x\tag{2.}$$
We can easily see that 
$$eq(1.)\le c\cdot eq(2.)\tag{3.}$$ for any arbitrary constant c. 
Now we know that if $\log a\le \log b$ then $a\le b$
Using this fact & Using inequality(3.) We can say that
$$L.H.S.\le R.H.S.$$thus
$$x^{100}=O(e^{x^{1/2}})$$ 
-Hence Proved